# Css background image doesn't show the image

Tags: css

I've [this simple code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-forked-z6we2w). Why `backgroundImage` seems not tot work?

I tried setting a fixed width and height but it's the same. Also tried using a png instead an svg.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the image is wrong.

try to test:

```
width: "300px",
height: "300px",
backgroundImage: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/1062/200/300.jpg?hmac=e6D9R3lyQ0AtilxM2LGviSrodxvroxcpCRm2FdfNwZg"),
```